# Is there a way to extract the missing field name from serde_json::Error?

Tags: json, rust, serde

serde_json returns a `serde_json::Error` when deserializing a field missing from the JSON but not optional in the struct. That error can be converted into a string and that string has the missing field name, generally of the form: `Error("missing field 'b'", line: 1, column: 9)`.

Short of parsing it out of that string, I cannot figure out how to extract the missing field name. Is string parsing really my only option?

Comment: This error is generated by the derived implementation of `Deserialize` on your struct rather than by `serde-json` itself. You can write your own implementation of `Deserialize` if you want to do something else in these cases. In any case, the error returned by `serde-json` actually only contains the message string, and does not provide the name of the missing field in a more structured way.